# Email on shutdown - ubuntu server 18.04

Tags: server, shutdown, email

I read all the questions that I have found, but I couldn't find the correct answer for my installation.

I have Ubuntu server 18.04 and I try to send an email when I power off or reboot my server.

What I did : I wrote the following service and I saved it to /etc/systemd/system with name shutdown_email.service

```
[Unit]
Description=Send an email on shutdown and reboot
Requires=network-online.target network.target postfix.service
Wants=network-online.target network.target postfix.service
After=network-online.target network.target postfix.service

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=true
ExecStop=/home/asus/shutdown_email.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

In the path /home/asus iI wrote the following, saved it as shutdown_email.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "You turned me off "  "$(date +"%A %d %B %Y %H:%M:%S" )" | mail -s "Title" my_email_address@gmail.com
postqueue -f
```

The service is running, i receive the correct email, but only when my system boots.

- Do you think that there is another service that i haven't include in the Unit section ?
- Is there any way to add delay, so the email queue will completed before the network services shuts down ?